# Java substring on delimiter not using split or regex

Tags: java, substring

I have a separate test class that is going to pass in a string with a high value and low value with a : in between, representing numbers 0-6. An example is "6:2". I need to separate these numbers based on the : delimiter, but my professor does not want me to use split or any regex.

```
public class DominoHighLowImpl_Laursen implements Domino {

public static final String HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR = ":";

public DominoHighLowImpl(String highLowString) 
{



}
```

So typing

```
String substr = highLowString.substring(highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR) + 1);
```

returned the number after the delimiter as I expected

BUT

```
String substr = highLowString.substring(highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR) - 1);
```

does not return the number before the delimiter. What am I doing wrong on the last part?

Comment: Have a look at [`substring(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) and [`substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [substring(int beginIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) and [substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```
String high = highLowString.substring(0, highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR));
String low = highLowString.substring(highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String substr = highLowString.substring(highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR) + 1);`  is working because `indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR)` is 1. So `substring(2)` will contain "2".

But when you do

`String substr = highLowString.substring(highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR) - 1)` the value becomes `indexOf(0)` so entire string "6:2" is stored.

**Try**

`String substr = highLowString.substring(0,highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR));`  to get "6".

Answer (score 1):

The `substring` method is overloaded, which means it may be called passing different amounts of `int` parameters / arguments. If you call it with just one, you will get the substring which begins at the passed index and ends at the maximum index of the `String`. If you call it with two parameters, you will receive the substring which begins at the lower index passed and ends **before** the second index passed.

See this example:

```
public class DominoHighLowImpl_Laursen {

    public static final String HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR = ":";

    private String highLowString;

    public DominoHighLowImpl_Laursen(String highLowString) {
        this.highLowString = highLowString;
    }

    public String getLow() {
        return highLowString.substring(0, highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR));
    }

    public String getHigh() {
        return highLowString.substring(highLowString.indexOf(HIGH_LOW_STRING_SEPARATOR) + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DominoHighLowImpl_Laursen domino = new DominoHighLowImpl_Laursen("1020304:4456778");

        System.out.println("High:\t" + domino.getHigh());
        System.out.println("Low:\t" + domino.getLow());
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be more efficient if you'd do those substring calls directly inside the constructor, but that is just a detail

Comment: @Lino totally right, but wouldn't be an illustrative example here. One should have two `String` attributes and define then via constructor. I think OP does not desire optimal efficiency in this case.